# How to find averages for each bin of a column

Tags: python, dataframe, mean

I have a data frame below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'A':[1.06, 1.01, 0.99, 0.98, 1.05, 0.96], 'B':[2, 7, 22, 7, 15, 16]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I want to find the mean of column B for each bin of column A.

For example, if I want to create bins of 0.02 starting the minimum value in column A, then bins will be like this (Inclusive):

```
1) 0.96-0.98
2) 0.99-1.01
3) 1.02-1.04
4) 1.05-1.07
```

The average of each bin will be

```
1) (16+7)/2 = 11.5 
2) (7+22)/2 = 14.5
3) 0
4) (2+15)/2 = 8.5
```

Thus, the outcome will look like:

```
df = {'A':[1.06, 1.01, 0.99, 0.98, 1.05, 0.96], 'B':[2, 7, 22, 7, 15, 16], 'Avg':[8.5, 14.5, 14.5, 11.5, 8.5, 11.5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

## LOGIC

You can make bins group and then use bins to group data and then apply [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) on `groupby` which will return the result for each row rather then grouped data.

PS: [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) is used for binning, assuming you have approach to get desired bins.

## SOLUTION

```py
import pandas as pd

df = {"A": [1.06, 1.01, 0.99, 0.98, 1.05, 0.96], "B": [2, 7, 22, 7, 15, 16]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df["cat"] = pd.cut(df["A"], [0.95, 0.98, 1.01, 1.04, 1.07], right=True)
print(df)
```

OUTPUT with Bins

```
      A   B           cat
0  1.06   2  (1.04, 1.07]
1  1.01   7  (0.98, 1.01]
2  0.99  22  (0.98, 1.01]
3  0.98   7  (0.95, 0.98]
4  1.05  15  (1.04, 1.07]
5  0.96  16  (0.95, 0.98]
```

```py
df["Avg"] = df.groupby("cat")["B"].transform("mean") 
# you can directly groupby pd.cut without making new column
print(df)
```

FINAL OUTPUT with average

```
      A   B           cat   Avg
0  1.06   2  (1.04, 1.07]   8.5
1  1.01   7  (0.98, 1.01]  14.5
2  0.99  22  (0.98, 1.01]  14.5
3  0.98   7  (0.95, 0.98]  11.5
4  1.05  15  (1.04, 1.07]   8.5
5  0.96  16  (0.95, 0.98]  11.5
```